# Deploying a asp.net website using team city

Tags: asp.net, teamcity, web-deployment

How to deploy a web site project, which does not have any project file.

we are trying to automate build and deployment using team city.

i am able to successfully build the project, but not able to deploy the web site.

Comment: How do you “able to successfully build the project” without project file? Do you use msbuild or a batch script?

Comment: i have used solution file.

Comment: Have you tried writing a command line or powershell script for the deploy process and adding it as a build step?

Comment: I am trying using Web deployment tool using command line. i will confirm once i successfully publish the same. thanks for your response.

Comment: By using below link i am able to deploy

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819407/how-to-use-command-line-msbuild-to-deploy-vs2012-web-site-project-without-precom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MsDeploy supports deployment of WebSites via `contentPath` provider:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:contentPath=WebSite\Deploy,computername=localhost -dest:auto...
```

Just change `WebSite\Deploy` to your actual path in your agent working directory, where is your builded website for deployment.

Comment: Thank you. By using MSbuild and website.publishproj file i am able to sucessfully deploy