# TeamCity MSBuild Web Site publishproj

Tags: web-applications, msbuild, web, teamcity, webdeploy

I have a Web Site project which I am trying to deploy via TeamCity and WebDeploy.

Because this is a Web Site and NOT a Web Application I do not have a .vbproj or .csproj file.

I have come to the conclusion from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819407/how-to-use-command-line-msbuild-to-deploy-vs2012-web-site-project-without-precom) post here that I need to create a .publishproj file as MSbuild uses this as it's build file.

However when TeamCity invokes MSBuild it bails with the following error:-

`Failed to start MSBuild.exe. Failed to detect default target(s) in the project file C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\d9dda73c7948f14a\MainSite\website.publishproj. Please define targets explicitly in the build configuration options on TeamCity Web UI. Project does not define DefaultTargets or InitialTargets.`

I have looked inside the .publishproj file and there is no Target defined.

I have also followed Troy Hunt's [You're deploying it wrong](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity.html) articles for a Web Application and this works fine.

Can anybody suggest how I Web Deploy a Web Site (NOT Web Application) from Team City ?

Answer (score 6):

I never worked with web-site-not-a-web-project so take it with a grain of salt.

`website.publishproj` seems to be create the moment you touch `Build` > `Publish Web Site` menu in Visual Studio and imports `Microsoft.WebSite.Publishing.targets` which is good cause it's the <s>same</s> similar targets file imported by your normal web projects (`Microsoft.WebApplication.targets`) and both of which import `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets`.

Unlike any project created by Visual Studio it doesn't have a `DefaultTargets = Build` nor `OutputPath` property, so you need to explicitly specify `Targets` in [MSBuild build step](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/MSBuild) with any targets defined in `Microsoft.WebSite.Publishing.targets` or `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets`.

You can call your standard `msbuild website.publishproj /t:Package /p:OutputPath=.\` to generate the `.cmd` and corresponding `.zip` in `obj\Debug\Package`. Then just call the `.cmd` or pass the `.zip` to the `msdeploy.exe -source:package=.zip` or try to do `/t:Build /p:DeployOnBuild=true` but I suspect you'd be missing a crap ton of properties predefined by your normal web project.

Edit:

There seems to be a circular reference somewhere and you end up with a package containing 2/3 copies of itself in `PackageTmp\_PublishedWebsites`, so play around with `OutDir`, `OutputPath`, `PackageDestinationRoot` and so on to get rid of the duplicates. Create a sample web project and read through the `.csproj` and `.targets` to get the idea.

Edit:

If you go through the publishing wizard you will also get `App_Data\PublishProfiles\Foo.pubxml` as well that's being read via `PublishProfileName`/`WebPublishProfileFile`, importing it would save time on some typing. [This](http://www.gregpakes.co.uk/post/msbuild-publish-profiles-and-web-site-projects) might be relevant.

Edit:

The import of proper web targets seems to be a new feature in 2012/2013, with 2010 you would need to use `aspnet_compiler`.

```
aspnet_compiler -v Foo -p . -f obj
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:iisApp=%CD%\obj -dest:iisApp="Default Web Site/foo"
```

Answer (score 2):

I found out in the end that for some reason I had to explicitly set the target to `Rebuild` in Team City for Web Site projects.

Answer (score 2):

Set the Build Step property **Targets** of the **Visual Studio (sln)** runner to `Package`.

Assuming you have the following directory structure:

```
\{Team City Working Directory}
  |
  |-- MyWebSite
  |    |-- App_Code
  |    |-- App_Data
  |    |    |
  |    |    \--PublishProfiles
  |    |         |
  |    |         \-- MyWebSite-Package.pubxml
  |    |
  |    | ... Other files and directories
  |    |
  |    |-- MyWebSite.publishproj
  |
  |-- SomeOtherLibraryProject
  |
  \-- MyWebSite.sln
```

Then, if you are specifying the solution file in the **Solution File Path** field of the build step, you should specify the following **Command Line Parameters** for the build step:

```
/p:PublishProfile=MyWebSite\App_Data\PublishProfiles\MyWebSite-Package.pubxml
```

However, you can also specify `.\MyWebSite\MyWebSite.publishproj` for the **Solution File Path** property of the build step; and if you do so, then you should specify the following **Command Line Parameters** instead:

```
/p:PublishProfile=App_Data\PublishProfiles\MyWebSite-Package.pubxml
```

The `PublishProfile` property is a relative path from the project or solution file specified in the **Solution File Path** property.