# ASP.NET Website Project auto deploy with TFS 2013 build

Tags: asp.net, tfs, msbuild, msdeploy, vs-web-site-project

I have a ASP.NET Webforms **Website project**(note this is **NOT** WebApplication project i.e. there is no .csproj).

I want to do a auto deploy, file system to our network share.

I created a profile and so there is website.publishproj file and profile xml.

I tried adding this in MSBuild arguments in Build Definition:

> website.publishproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true
>   /p:PublishProfile=MyDevProfile /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0

I get this error:

> MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified. Switch:
>   website.publishproj

Any idea what am I doing wrong? I believe this has something to do with Website project type.

This is something I read: [How to use command line msbuild to deploy VS2012 Web Site project without precompiling it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819407/how-to-use-command-line-msbuild-to-deploy-vs2012-web-site-project-without-precom)

Here is the command:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe /nologo
>   /noconsolelogger
>   "E:\Builds\1\TP1\MyWebsite_Dev\src\Websites\MyWebsite\MyWebsite.sln"
>   /nr:False /fl
>   /flp:"logfile=E:\Builds\1\TP1\MyWebsite_Dev\src\Websites\MyWebsite\MyWebsite.log;encoding=Unicode;verbosity=normal"
>   /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true website.publishproj
>   /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=DropToDemoProfile
>   /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0 /m
>   /p:OutDir="E:\Builds\1\TP1\MyWebsite_Dev\bin\"
>   /p:VCBuildOverride="E:\Builds\1\TP1\MyWebsite_Dev\src\Websites\MyWebsite\MyWebsite.sln.vsprops"
>   /dl:WorkflowCentralLogger,"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation
>   Server
>   12.0\Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.Logger.dll";"Verbosity=Normal;BuildUri=vstfs:///Build/Build/35;IgnoreDuplicateProjects=False;InformationNodeId=13;TargetsNotLogged=GetNativeManifest,GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems,GetTargetPath;LogWarnings=True;TFSUrl=`http://mytfs:8080/tfs/colletionname`;"*WorkflowForwardingLogger,"C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server
>   12.0\Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.Logger.dll";"Verbosity=Normal;"
>   /p:BuildId="7d23530d-7349-406f-98b7-5d4f0b9f4101,vstfs:///Build/Build/35"
>   /p:BuildLabel="MyWebsite_Dev_20141122.13" /p:BuildTimestamp="Sun, 23
>   Nov 2014 01:22:05 GMT"
>   /p:BuildSourceVersion="LMyWebsite_Dev_20141122.13@$/TP1"
>   /p:BuildDefinition="MyWebsite_Dev"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to build the solution (`MyWebsite.sln`) and the project (`website.publishproj`) simultaneously as part of the same MSBuild command at least according to the arguments being passed.

You can run `msbuild website.publishproj /pp:website.pp.publishproj` to see what targets you can call in `website.pp.publishproj` or what properties to override.

You can run `set MSBUILDEMITSOLUTION=true && msbuild MyWebsite.sln` to see what targets you can call in `MyWebsite.sln.metaproj` and `MyWebsite.metaproj` or what properties to override.

Your `DeployOnBuild` command is fine and should work, I'm guessing your TFS build config is pointing to the `.sln` and passing `website.publishproj` as an argument rather than the primary target of the build, so either repoint it to build the `.publishproj` directly or... well, there doesn't seem to be any alternative, you can try adding a new configuration and editing the `.sln` with new `AspNetConfiguration` and `MyDevProfile.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath` but then you're just asking for trouble.

Comment: The first para makes sense. For the 2nd and 3rd para I don't get that. Haven't done much with msbuild. 4th Para - I did try adding the website.publishproj to the build projects list but it wasn't working as well. I don't recall the error, but I can try again and post. Say I add a .targets file at the solution level and want to add afterbuild target, what would the command look like? Can I set postbuild script in TFS? If yes, what would that script look like? Thanks.

Comment: @gbs post the error from `publishproj` build. 2/3 are commands you might use to *preparse* the `publishproj` and *emit* the `sln` if you want to read through what is actually being executed by MSBuild and see all the targets that can be called, properties available to override, etc. Yes, you can have a custom build script and all the targets and events you want that in turn build the `sln` and `publishproj`, why not, command remains the same, just pass the filename to MSBuild or configure TFS to build that instead.

Comment: I tried again with adding .publishproj to the build process and removed it from the build argument. Now it seems it's trying to deploy to my path: \\devserver\www\dropbuild\mywebsite but it is giving Access denied to that path. I actually gave permission to Everyone to that folder not sure what am I missing.

Comment: never mind...I added everyone but forgot to grant full control. But now what is the right way to grant access to that folder instead of using Everyone. Do I create a separate account and have TFS Build run under that account?

Comment: @gbs yes, or you can grant it to whichever account agent service is running under, normally Network Service.

Comment: Is Network Service available outside of the host machine? And is it a good idea to give permission to that account?

Comment: @gbs yes, if it's on a domain; not it is not, but sometimes creating a dedicated service account in a big todo in a corporate environment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your Web Site to a Web Application in order for any of this to be automatic.

Its a fairly simple procedure and even on sites with thousands of pages I have completed the migration in only a few days of one persons time without impacting other devs.

Web Site functionality has been feature complete for over 10 years. While it still existing in the product for back-compat I would not recommend using it.

Comment: Yes, but until then do you see anything wrong in the above command? Most my findings points to space in the path which I couldn't find. The build arguments way did work for me in one of my test website but not with my real website.