# tfs vsts-agent msbuild package as a single file doesn't produce any output

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, msbuild, azure-devops

On my TFS build box, I am building a website using msbuild with the following switches (breaking up on several lines for readability)...

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe" 
"C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\ALM.TestWeb.sln" 
/nologo 
/nr:false 
/p:DeployOnBuild=true 
/p:WebPublishMethod=Package 
/p:PackageAsSingleFile=true 
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true 
/p:PackageLocation="C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\a\\" 
/p:platform="any cpu" 
/p:configuration="release" 
/p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0" 
/p:_MSDeployUserAgent="TFS_b703cd8a-0160-43cb-8b4e-6da302e2005d_build_36_1583"
```

The plan is that TFS builds the website and zips everything into a zip in the above directory.  It doesn't do that, and I don't know why.  Here's the log of the build if this helps at all...

```
    ==============================================================================
Task         : Visual Studio Build
Description  : Build with MSBuild and set the Visual Studio version property
Version      : 1.119.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613727)
==============================================================================
"C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [15.0,16.0) -latest -format json
"C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [15.0,16.0) -products Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.BuildTools -latest -format json
Visual Studio version '15.0' not found. Falling back to version '14.0'.
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe" "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\ALM.TestWeb.sln" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=6808b8db-39de-488d-9517-f57544cac9ba|SolutionDir=C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s"*ForwardingLogger,"C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\a\\" /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="TFS_b703cd8a-0160-43cb-8b4e-6da302e2005d_build_36_1583"
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 10/1/2017 11:45:11 AM.
Project "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\ALM.TestWeb.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "release|any cpu".
Project "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\ALM.TestWeb.sln" (1) is building "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\ALM.TestWeb\ALM.TestWeb.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin\".
  Creating directory "obj\Release\".
ResolveAssemblyReferences:
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "WebGrease, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "1.5.1.25624" [] to Version "1.5.2.14234" [C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\WebGrease.1.5.2\lib\WebGrease.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" from Version "4.5.0.0" [] to Version "6.0.0.0" [C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): Warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file: <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding>
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file: <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding> [C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\ALM.TestWeb\ALM.TestWeb.csproj]
CoreCompile:
  C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\build\..\tools\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Antlr.3.4.1.9004\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll /reference:C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept.2.0.6\lib\net45\Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept.dll /reference:C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.2.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector.dll /reference:C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector.2.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector.dll /reference:C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.2.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel.dll /reference:C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.2.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AI.Web...
_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Antlr.3.4.1.9004\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll" to "bin\Antlr3.Runtime.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept.2.0.6\lib\net45\Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept.dll" to "bin\Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.2.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector.dll" to "bin\Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector.2.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector.dll" to "bin\Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.2.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel.dll" to "bin\Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.2.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AI.Web.dll" to "bin\Microsoft.AI.Web.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.2.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer.dll" to "bin\Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.2.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll" to "bin\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.3\lib\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll" to "bin\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll" to "bin\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" to "bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Helpers.dll" to "bin\System.Web.Helpers.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll" to "bin\System.Web.Mvc.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3\lib\net40\System.Web.Optimization.dll" to "bin\System.Web.Optimization.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Razor.dll" to "bin\System.Web.Razor.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" to "bin\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.dll" to "bin\System.Web.WebPages.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll" to "bin\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\WebGrease.1.5.2\lib\WebGrease.dll" to "bin\WebGrease.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.3\lib\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.xml" to "bin\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.xml".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Helpers.xml" to "bin\System.Web.Helpers.xml".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.xml" to "bin\System.Web.Mvc.xml".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3\lib\net40\System.Web.Optimization.xml" to "bin\System.Web.Optimization.xml".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Razor.xml" to "bin\System.Web.Razor.xml".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.xml" to "bin\System.Web.WebPages.xml".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.xml" to "bin\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.xml".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.xml" to "bin\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.xml".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Antlr.3.4.1.9004\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.pdb" to "bin\Antlr3.Runtime.pdb".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.xml" to "bin\Newtonsoft.Json.xml".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.2.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.xml" to "bin\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.xml".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.2.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector.xml" to "bin\Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector.xml".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.2.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel.xml" to "bin\Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel.xml".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.2.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer.xml" to "bin\Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer.xml".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.2.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AI.Web.xml" to "bin\Microsoft.AI.Web.xml".
_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory:
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\ALM.TestWeb\ApplicationInsights.config" to "bin\ApplicationInsights.config".
  Creating directory "bin\roslyn".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\csc.exe" to "bin\roslyn\csc.exe".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\csc.exe.config" to "bin\roslyn\csc.exe.config".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\csc.rsp" to "bin\roslyn\csc.rsp".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\csi.exe" to "bin\roslyn\csi.exe".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\csi.rsp" to "bin\roslyn\csi.rsp".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll" to "bin\roslyn\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll" to "bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting.dll" to "bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll" to "bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.dll" to "bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.dll" to "bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" to "bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll" to "bin\roslyn\Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.x86.dll" to "bin\roslyn\Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.x86.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.targets" to "bin\roslyn\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.targets".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\System.AppContext.dll" to "bin\roslyn\System.AppContext.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\System.Collections.Immutable.dll" to "bin\roslyn\System.Collections.Immutable.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll" to "bin\roslyn\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\System.IO.FileSystem.dll" to "bin\roslyn\System.IO.FileSystem.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll" to "bin\roslyn\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll" to "bin\roslyn\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\vbc.exe" to "bin\roslyn\vbc.exe".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\vbc.exe.config" to "bin\roslyn\vbc.exe.config".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\vbc.rsp" to "bin\roslyn\vbc.rsp".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\VBCSCompiler.exe" to "bin\roslyn\VBCSCompiler.exe".
  Copying file from "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\VBCSCompiler.exe.config" to "bin\roslyn\VBCSCompiler.exe.config".
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  Copying file from "obj\Release\ALM.TestWeb.dll" to "bin\ALM.TestWeb.dll".
  ALM.TestWeb -> C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\ALM.TestWeb\bin\ALM.TestWeb.dll
  Copying file from "obj\Release\ALM.TestWeb.pdb" to "bin\ALM.TestWeb.pdb".
Done Building Project "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\ALM.TestWeb\ALM.TestWeb.csproj" (default targets).
Done Building Project "C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\ALM.TestWeb.sln" (default targets).
Build succeeded.
"C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\ALM.TestWeb.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\ALM.TestWeb\ALM.TestWeb.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
(ResolveAssemblyReferences target) -> 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file: <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding> [C:\buildagent\agent1\_work\1\s\ALM.TestWeb\ALM.TestWeb.csproj]
    1 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:05.35
```

It would be greatly appreciated if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.  Thank you!

Comment: You're saying "it doesn't do that." Okay, so what **does** it do? Do you get a zip fie in a different location? Do you get unzipped files in the package location?

Comment: Also, did you try specifying `/p:OutDir=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`?

Comment: The zip file is not produced anywhere.

Comment: The build step I actually have it defined to output to $(build.artifactstagingdirectory).  I am showing the resolved path.

Comment: Yes, I believe I do get the compiled files in the normal output directory.  I will verify in a bit.

Comment: Try using `/p:OutDir=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses Daniel.  /p:OutDir puts the compiled output into build.artifactstagingdirectory but no zip.

Comment: I think there is a discrepancy with the working folders. In the first block you have `C:\agentnew\Agent3\_work\11\s`, but in the output your working folder seems to be `c:\bld\49\s` ?

Comment: @NielZeeman Updated the post so that the command matches the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon analysis of the logs, I noticed that the Web folder was missing from...

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0

Found out one of the build engineers was freeing up space on the build server.  He uninstalled Visual Studio 2015 and installed Visual Studio 2015 Build Tools.  As far as I can tell, it doesn't install everything it needs to build websites.

The fix was installing Visual Studio 2015 with Microsoft Web Developers Tools checked.

Comment: So, do you mean you can create package through MSBuild tool directly? What's the detail setting?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can archive output files to a zip file, then deploy it.

Secondly, after creating publish profile (right click the website=>Publish web app=>Custom=>Web Deploy Package), it will creates the **xx.publishproj** file, which is used to publish website app.

So, you can specify this file to build and publish in Visual Studio Build task.
There is a related thread: [How to use command line msbuild to deploy VS2012 Web Site project without precompiling it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819407/how-to-use-command-line-msbuild-to-deploy-vs2012-web-site-project-without-precom)

Comment: I'll try this today as a workaround.  I would really like to know why msbuild doesn't generate the zip.

Comment: Making the zip file using an extra step doesn't create the set_parameters.xml.  This is a problem.